# Filter legend entry for raster layer QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, legend

Is it possible to use the "Filter legend by Map content" button, or achieve the same functionality with a raster layer?

I've got a map that has a dozen different raster layers, but am only displaying one at time in a map composer.  The item properties for legends has a button for filtering legend content to only include legend items for layers that are displayed in the current composer.  This works very well for vector layers, but doesn't seem to have an effect on raster layers.

I would like to include layer entries for each of the raster layers, but only display them when the associated layer is displayed.

Comment: I have the same issues